# passing value of arraylist to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, arraylist

I have the arraylist in one jsp.i want arraylist value in java script on another jsp.Can you please tell me how to do it.Following is my code.i have two jsp.

getuser.jsp

---

```
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
            String query = "select user_registeration_code from system_user_master where user_first_name ='"+firstname+"' and user_last_name='"+lastname+"' and user_phone_no='"+emp_id+"'";
       st = conn.createStatement();

       ArrayList<String> addressLists1 = new ArrayList<String>();
           ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);
           while(rs.next())
                {


               addressLists1.add(rs.getString("user_registeration_code"));


                }
                out.println(addressLists1.size());
                //out.println(data);
                request.setAttribute("top", addressLists1);
```

second.jsp

---

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >


function showEmp(emp_value) {

    var fname = document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value;
    alert(fname);
    var lname = document.getElementById("txtlastname").value;
    alert(lname);
    if (document.getElementById("txtmobileno").value != "") {
        alert("1");
        xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp == null) {
            alert("2");
            alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
        }
        var url = "getuser.jsp";
        url = url + "?emp_id=" + emp_value + "&firstname=" + fname + "&lastname=" + lname;

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);

    } else {
        alert("Please Select Employee Id");
    }
}

function stateChanged() {
    alert("3");
    document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txtmobileno").value = "";
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {

        alert("4");
        var showdata = [];
        showdata = xmlHttp.responseText;
        alert("qqqqqqqqq" + showdata.length);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < showdata.length; i++) {
            alert("----------------" + showdata.get(i));
        }
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        //Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

< /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in getuser.jsp change

```
 request.setAttribute("top", addressLists1);
```

to

```
 session.setAttribute("top", addressLists1);
```

Then in second.jsp something like

```
 ArrayList<String> addressLists1 = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("top");
```

and then iterate through that and print the list into your html/javascript output.

By the way, if you're going to be connecting to a database in a JSP then at the very least the two lines of code where you connect to the database should be moved into a class that you use in the JSP rather than just having those lines in the JSP itself.  Its a very bad idea to have the database connection part in the JSP.  If your db servername and password are in the JSP, and the JSP encounters a runtime error causing it to show the user the offending lines of code, your db password may get exposed to the user.